# Bootstrap: highlight active menu links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i've this website (made with Bootstrap) http://sg.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/ and i need to highlight the active menu links (maybe via CSS).

This is the code i'm using:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" data-activeslide="1">
    <div class="container">


        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>


        <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <ul class="nav row">

                <li data-slide="2" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-2" href="#slide-2" title="Next Section"> <span class="text">Home</span></a></li>
                <li data-slide="4" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-4" href="#slide-4" title="Next Section"> <span class="text">Mental Coaching</span></a></li>
                <li data-slide="5" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-5" href="#slide-5" title="Next Section"> <span class="text">Personal Training</span></a></li>
                <li data-slide="6" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-6" href="#slide-6" title="Next Section"> <span class="text">Ernährungsberatung</span></a></li>
                <li data-slide="7" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-7" href="#slide-7" title="Next Section"> <span class="text">Kontakt</span></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

Comment: the website doesn't exist anymore. thererfore, this post is obsolete.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use jQuery `addClass` and `removeClass` method.

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
li{
  padding: 8px;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:hover, a:focus{
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.active{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
  });
```

Working fiddle:

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ko4L5fgu/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Add a custom made CSS file after loading the Bootstrap CSS.

```
.nav a:hover{
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: sorry i just edited the question. What i need is to highlight the active anchor point

Comment: You could use the [scrollspy](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) javascript plugin from Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean on hover

```
.nav span:hover {
color: red;
```

}

Comment: Mmmh no. I mean to put something like a border-bottom when you click on the anchor point, so you knwo where you are (looking at the navbar)

Comment: .nav span:hover {
border-bottom:2px solid red;